# Spring MVC. No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc

What is wrong with my views?

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.wordparty")
class AppConfig {
}

@Controller
class IndexController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showIndex() {
       return "index";
   }
```

}

Here is my package structure

```
main
--java
----com.wordparty
      ...
--webapp
----WEB-INF
------view
--------index.jsp
```

I recieve 404 response. And in console I see message that my page wasn't found. If I write @ResponseBody then it returns text from controller without problems...
Where is a mistake?

P.S. I am using Spring 4 + Java 8

Comment: What URL did you enter?

Comment: my application on root

Comment: Please enter it in full.  Either the URL or the deployment is incorrect.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Does your web.xml have a <welcome-file-list> entry that includes index.jsp?

Comment: There is no web.xml in my app. I want to achieve pure annotation configuration..

Comment: web.xml is a Java EE requirement for WAR deployments; has nothing to do with Spring.  You have to have one in order to deploy properly.  No wonder you're getting 404.

Comment: But I am using the newest Servlet Api..

Comment: @duffymo Servlet 3.0 has since provided a Java based deployment method. Spring has its own implementation of that in the form of `WebApplicationInitializer` and its subtypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.. my dispatcher servlet has /* mapping instead of /